# Windows 10 Pro doesn't update to 2004 version?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, updates, windows-10-v2004

I had a Dell laptop with Windows 10 Pro, version 1804, installed.

Due to some performance issues, we disabled the update service five months ago.
Now we enabled it again and tried to update to the latest version.
It updated from 1804 to 1903.
It should next update to 1909 and then to 2004.

But when checking for updates in
*Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update*, it says:
"You're up-to-date."

I think there are no hardware compatibility issues for the 2004 update in my laptop.
Because when checking for updates, it shows no such errors.

Why am I not getting further updates? Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: What is the last cumulative update that was installed

Comment: Try to use the [Update Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

Comment: Please try to: Select Start  > Settings  > Update & Security  > Troubleshoot. Next, under Get up and running, select Windows Update > Run the troubleshooter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Windows media creation tool downloaded from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to do an in-place upgrade of my windows 10 OS.

I followed the steps as described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/how-to-perform-an-in-place-upgrade-with-windows-10/7f0b236e-3c6c-4913-9691-c4baa2a6190a) in the video.

After downloading and installing the update, the machine rebooted and it was stuck for 3-4 hours during the first reboot. After waiting for this much of time, rebooted the laptop manually by pressing it's power button. This time windows 10 pro booted properly.

After login, checked the windows version. And it was the latest one!

```
version: 20H2
```

Answer (score 5):

When a compatibility problem prevents an upgrade, Windows gives you an explicit message about this. It looks like your computer is at the end of a staged rollout queue.

You can force an upgrade by [downloading Windows 10 version 2004 from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10) and running `setup.exe` from a booted Windows installation. It will offer an in-place upgrade.

Comment: What exactly does "staged rollout queue" mean, and is it documented anywhere? Does it mean that my computer will never ever receive a feature update again? I find it had to find good documentation about the different reasons why computers are not receiving an update, especially because some get a notification that an upgrade is in preparation.

Comment: @Erik _Staged rollout_ means that a new version isn't released for everyone simultaneously, but just for a small part of the userbase which is extended to entire userbase over time. If the new version turns out to have a serious issue that wasn't caught during internal testing, only a small percentage of users will be affected and the vendor can patch it before next stage or retract the update until the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Update page in Settings will say "You are up-to-date" if there are
no updates for your current version, which is version 1903.
It will offer below the latest version under the header of "Feature update",
if available.

Try to use the
[Update Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
to do the upgrade to version 2004.
If it offers version 1909, don't force it, install this version and wait
for Microsoft to decide that version 2004 has been tested enough on
your computer setup.

Comment: I used windows 10 update assistant . When i ran it, it says to update to 2004. I clicked 'update now' and the downloading started. After around 20% downloading, that update assistant window closed suddenly. When tried to run it again, it was saying that "update assistant is already running". Is that an error? How can i know that the update finished or not? What should i do in this situation?

Comment: If you were not asked to reboot, then it didn't finish. You can check your version by running the command `winver`. Something is wrong. To check your system, run `chkdsk` and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).