# Why is my PC blocked from receiving Windows 10 Update 2004 or 20H2

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1909, windows-10-v2004

I am currently operating an older PC running a core i5-2500K CPU, which is sufficient for my purposes, OS ist Win10 Pro 1909.

I am wondering why I do not get an update to Windows 10 2004 or even the latest 20H2 offered, even if I manually search for it through Windows update.

I know that many users who experience this block get a message in Windows update saying "An upgrade is in preparation, please be patient". But on my system, everything is different. Windows update tells me that my system is up to date, and when I search for an update, it doesn't find anything. However, I get the regular security updates, so I doubt there is something generally wrong with the update service itself.

So my questions are:

- Why is my PC blocked from receiving updates to 2004 or 20H2? How can I find the reason?
- Why is there no notification on my system that an update is in preparation, like on many others?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 pro doesn't updated to 2004 version?](https://superuser.com/questions/1595774/windows-10-pro-doesnt-updated-to-2004-version)

Comment: If you don't get the 2004 some incompatibility has been detected. You can update system drivers (e.g. display drivers) and other programs that integrate deeply into the system. May be one of them is the blocker.

Comment: Windows 10 has a task in the task scheduler that determines the compatibility. If for whatever reason this check is not carried out, the update will not be offered in Windows Update either.
You can read more about the topic there: https://www.asquaredozen.com/2020/07/26/demystifying-windows-10-feature-update-blocks

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft continues to hold back Windows 10 2004 and 20H2 for machines that its tests deem not yet ready - that is, more change to Windows 10 to fix.

Best approach is to wait and definitely do not force the update.

The update will happen (nominally some Patch Tuesday) and your regular Windows 10 Updates will tell you when V2004 is ready for it.

In the meantime, you will get Security Updates.

Note for Information:  There are roughly 16 Million combinations of computers and drivers. Microsoft needs to have Window 10 compliant with all these and this is part of the delay for some computers.